# Measuring time consumed for each make operation in recursive folders

Tags: makefile, measure, gnu-make

I am very new to makefile. Here i have challenge in finding time for the compiling(c code) each module.

Operating system:Linux
make : x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu

I am using "make" with `-j` option.only one Makefile maintained having instruction "`/usr/bin/make`".
And recursivley there are multiple Components are there .For each component one Config.mk maintained.
some modules doesnt have "`.mk`" also
I tried to echo time  in each ".mk" using "{info {shell date}),but it didn't give enough results,since they all been used in very early stage of compilation..

Could anyone help in finding time for each make operation

Cheers
Murali

Comment: Please show us your master makefile. And tell us which OS you use. And perhaps tell us your native language, since it does not appear to be English.

Comment: Operating system is Linux.

Comment: I do not clearly understand what you want to measure. Every make target of its own or the complete make process to find the right numver for `-j`? As far as i got it, I think `time` will help you. Replace make calls by `time make` should give you some first hints.

Comment: sorry for unclear query.Measure is only "how much time taking for each compilation or generating an object file from c code".                          As mentioned,only single Makefile maintained and called via " make -j " which internally loops many directories(components) having "config.mk" files to compile each module. My need is to find "compilation time for each component".                              "time make" didnt help me.Is there any option with "debug"?

Answer (score 0):

You can  .PHONY targets that are executed as first and last targets and print out the date

```
all:
    echo "Component foo: build started"
    date
    $(MAKE) build
    echo "Component foo: build finished"
    date

build: ....
    ....
```